Getting the type of every argument in a variadic macro argument list?
I have a macro like this:
#define ptapply(pt, ret_type, identifier, ...) ((ret_type (*)()) pget(pt, identifier))(pt __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)

pget returns a void * which I cast into a function pointer and call. Because I don't know the number of arguments and their types, I have to use ret_type (*)() which is fine most of the time, but if one of the arguments has types such as float, char, short or etc things get messed up because C's default promotion rules converts those types to double and int. If I somehow could use typeof on every argument in __VA_ARGS__ I could cast the void * pointer into the exact function pointer type but I don't know how. Is there a way?

I wonder - what is this code supposed to do? Are you working with dlsym? Why not use static type checking and define the pointer and call void (*pointer)(pt_type, float, int) = pget(pt, identifier); pointer(pt, 1.0, 1)? C is not dynamic - if you make an error, all hell breaks loose.

Maybe you can rework your problem to using _Generic? See C11 6.5.1.1

Using variable argument lists, C assumes that your called function(s) know the types of the variable arguments — somehow.  For example, the printf() family of functions have the format string to guide them; so does the scanf() family of functions.  If you have no idea what types are in use, you really can't do much in C.

Converting between function pointers and void* is not well-defined. If you need a general-purpose function pointer then just use any function pointer type and cast to/from the actual function pointer type. So this whole thing is flawed from the start, you need to re-design pget to begin with.

It's simple - overload the macro on number of arguments and apply __typeof__ on each macro element. I like following overload style. The following code compiles on GCC. __typeof__ is something in gcc, I do not know if it is in C23.
#include <stdio.h>
void *pget(int, int) {
    return dprintf;
}

#define TYPES_1(a)       __typeof__(a)
#define TYPES_2(a, ...)  __typeof__(a), TYPES_1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define TYPES_3(a, ...)  __typeof__(a), TYPES_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define TYPES_4(a, ...)  __typeof__(a), TYPES_3(__VA_ARGS__)
#define TYPES_N(_4,_3,_2,_1,_0,N,...)  TYPES_##N
#define TYPES(...)  \
    TYPES_N(0 __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__,4,3,2,1)(__VA_ARGS__)

#define ptapply(pt, ret_type, identifier, ...) \
    ((ret_type (*)(__typeof__(pt), TYPES(__VA_ARGS__))) pget(pt, identifier))\
    (pt __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
    ptapply(1, int, 0, "%s %d\n", "Hello", 5);
}

Notes:

I would strongly rather recommend against using such methods. I would recommend first defining the pointer void (*pointer)(pt_type, float, int) = pget(pt, identifier); and then calling it pointer(pt, 1.0, 1). The code will cause headaches, as the parameter types are dynamic from the declared type, which I do not think is something C programmers would expect.
Code casting void * to pointer type is inherently non-portable , but "will work" everywhere. See for example Casting when using dlsym() .
The code above is invalid. dprintf is cast to int (*)(int, const char*, const char *, int) pointer type and then called, which is wrong.


Both typeof and typeof_unqual are full keywords in C23.  The latter identifies the "non-atomic unqualified version of the type" name.  According to example 2 in the standard (p118), typeof_unqual does not always remove all the qualifiers, so understanding what it does do takes more understanding than I've yet got.

@JonathanLeffler That example made me confused too. It appears to be a gcc 14.2 bug which is fixed in gcc trunk version. See typeof_unqual behaves differently in gcc and clang
